# Move all future appointments in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

I have an appointment repeating every 4 days. After a certain period, I want to move all future appointment of that event one day. How can I do this?

Let me provide an example to be more clear.

```
1. 02/01/2016
2. 02/05/2016
3. 02/09/2016
4. 02/12/2016
5. 02/16/2016
6. 02/20/2016
```

Appointments 1-3 have the regular dates according to the defined schedule. From appointment 4 onwards, I want to move all appointments one day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do this...

1. Edit the event from which the day/date should change (ie. **#4 02/12/2016** in the example)
2. Change the date (eg. advance by one day), change the repeat frequency, etc.
3. Click <kbd>Save</kbd>.

   You then get prompted whether you want "to change only this event, or this and all future events in the series". Click <kbd>Following events</kbd>. Note, however, that "any changes [that have been made] to future events will be lost".

Note that this edited series of events are now considered a "new series of events". So, for example, if you went back to event **#1** and decided to delete the lot, it would only delete **#1**, **#2** and **#3**.

(This was tested on the web interface.)